# How to delete a foreign key row when the key it's referencing get's deleted? [SQLAlchemy]

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, sqlite3-python

I have three tables: User, File, and UserFile

The first stored data about users including username, email, password, and all of their files.

The second stores info about files.

The third connects a user to a file in order to create a list of shared users.

```
class Base(sqlalchemy.orm.DeclarativeBase):

    __allow_unmapped__ = True

class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    token = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                              primary_key=True)
    
    username = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                                 nullable=False)
    
    email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                              nullable=False)
    
    password = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                                 nullable=False)
    
    files = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('File',
                                        backref='users')
    
    bytes_used = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                   nullable=False)
    
    total_bytes = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                    nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self,
                 username: str,
                 email: str,
                 password: str):

        while db.query(User).filter(
              User.token == (token:=secrets.token_urlsafe(32))).first():
            pass
        
        self.token = token

        self.username = username

        self.email = email

        self.password = password

        self.bytes_used = 0

        self.total_bytes = 1_000_000_000 # 1 GB

class File(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'files'

    token = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                              primary_key = True)
    
    filename = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                             nullable = False)
    
    size = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                             nullable = False)
    
    data = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.BLOB,
                             nullable = False)
    
    owner = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                              sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('users.token'))
    
    share_list = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('UserFile',
                                             uselist = True,
                                             backref = 'files')
    
    def __init__(self,
                 filename: str,
                 data: bytes,
                 owner_token: str):

        while db.query(File).filter(
              File.token == (token:=secrets.token_urlsafe(32))).first():
            pass
        
        self.token = token

        self.filename = filename

        self.size = len(data)

        self.data = data

        db.query(User).filter(User.token == owner_token).first().bytes_used += self.size

        self.owner = owner_token

        self.share_list = []

class UserFile(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'user_files'

    user_token = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                                   sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('users.token'),
                                   primary_key = True)
    file_token = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                                   sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('files.token'),
                                   primary_key = True)
    
    def __init__(self,
                 user_token: str,
                 file_token: str):
        
        self.user_token = user_token
        self.file_token = file_token

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so when a user is deleted, that all the files associated with it are also deleted, and any UserFile rows referencing it's token is deleted as well.

I also want to make it so that when a File is deleted that all the UserFile row referencing it's token are deleted.

I think I have to use some kind of ForeignKeyConstraint, but I haven't been able to find any solutions online.